# Get a row from a range based on a single value in column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a spreadsheet to store highscores. I have one column (Initials [Column D]) and one column (Scores [Column E]). They are already sorted from highest to lowest (dependent upon the Scores). I want to get the first occurrence of all initials and that initials score.

For example if I had this:

```
|Initials|Scores|
| ABC    | 5    |
| NOT    | 4    |
| ABC    | 2    |
| LOL    | 1    |
```

I want to get this:

```
|Initials|Scores|
| ABC    | 5    |
| NOT    | 4    |
| LOL    | 1    |
```

I've been able to get just the names portion with `=UNIQUE(D:D)`, but how would one also get the scores from the next column? I've been trying for a while now, and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values in E are already sorted, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique(filter(D2:D, len(D2:D))), D2:E, {1,2}, 0))
```

of if you want to use a limited range:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique(D2:D50), D2:E50, {1,2}, 0))
```

See if that works ?